# Error message npm-default is unavailable

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, opensuse

I updated the **npm** in opensuse 42.2 leap and after that, I got this error:

> npm-default is unavailable.

I look inside the npm:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROG=$(basename $0)
PROG_VERSION=${NODE_VERSION:--default}

if [ ! -x /usr/bin/${PROG}${PROG_VERSION} ]; then
    echo "${PROG}${PROG_VERSION} is unavailable."
    exit 127
fi
exec /usr/bin/${PROG}${PROG_VERSION} "$@"
```

I figured out that the `NODE_VERSION` is not defined, so I added it to env:

**export NODE_VERSION=8**

Then I got this msg:

> npm8 is unavailable.

But:

**ls -la /usr/bin/npm8**:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 okt   17 14.46 /usr/bin/npm8 ->
>   ../lib64/node_modules/npm8/bin/npm-cli.js

Finally I tried these:

**npm8**:

> bash: /usr/bin/npm8: Permission denied

**sudo npm8**:

> sudo: npm8: command not found

I think the latest npm update has some problem, but I don't know how can I fix it.
Did anybody else meet this problem?

I've already tried reinstall the packages.

Comment: What's the output of npm --version?

Comment: @MilanVelebit thx the comment. `npm --version`: _npm-default is unavailable._  But I git the version via rpm: `rpm -qa | grep npm` -> _npm8-8.7.0-13.1.x86_64_

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.. so wierd, but thx for the hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague figured out the problem; I had to add an **executable right** for **/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm8/npm-cli.js** file.